# Video Carousel slider for flutter

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout

I know there is image carousel slider, but what I need is video carousel slider. I manage to add video to carousel slider using chewie but don't know how to auto transfer to next video when the present video finish playing.

```
        class _ChewieDemoState extends State<ChewieDemo> {
          TargetPlatform _platform;
          VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController1;
          VideoPlayerController _videoPlayerController2;
          ChewieController _chewieController;
          ChewieController _chewieController2;
          void initState() {
          super.initState();
          _videoPlayerController1 = VideoPlayerController.network(
            'https://flutter.github.io/assets-for-api-docs/assets/videos/butterfly.mp4');
          _videoPlayerController2 = VideoPlayerController.network(
            'https://www.sample-videos.com/video123/mp4/720/big_buck_bunny_720p_1mb.mp4');

          _chewieController = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController1,
          aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
          autoPlay: true,
          looping: false,
          );

          _chewieController2 = ChewieController(
          videoPlayerController: _videoPlayerController2,
          aspectRatio: 4 / 3,
          autoPlay: true,
          looping: false,);}
```

In widget build

```
body: CarouselSlider(
      items: [Chewie( controller: _chewieController,),Chewie(controller: _chewieController2,)],
      autoPlay: true,
      autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 1),
      autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
        ),
```

I'm thinking of this solution : get duration time of video and put it in autoPlayInterval, change duration to the present video everytime slide change .

```
autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: duration),
```

there is  onPageChanged: callbackFunction, but i don't understand how it work, i change duration in there but not affect anything.

Code for auto change slide when video end.

```
goToNext() {
    carouselSlider.nextPage(
        duration: Duration(seconds: 1), curve: Curves.decelerate);
  }
void checkVideo(){

    if(_videoPlayerController1.value.position == _videoPlayerController1.value.duration){
      print('video Ended');
      _videoPlayerController1.seekTo(Duration(seconds:0 )); // If i don't put this here it will keep transfer to nextpage.
      goToNext();
      _videoPlayerController2.seekTo(Duration(seconds:0 ));
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When the current video ends, you could tell the slider to go to the next page.

- To know when the video ends, you can add a listener to the video controller
- To tell the slider to go to the next page, you can call the nextPage() instance method of the slider:
  [Carousel Slider: Instance methods](https://pub.dev/packages/carousel_slider#instance-methods) - 
  [Carousel Slider: Example with instance methods](https://github.com/serenader2014/flutter_carousel_slider/blob/master/example/lib/main.dart)

Comment: sorry for late reply, I try your way, it work but if I move video postion back it will play a little then slider go to next page when time up. Example:  video duration is 7 ,it play to 00:04 then I move it to 00:00 then it will play 3 more second and move to next page. Anyway to prevent it? I  just add the code

Comment: what are you checking on the controller listener to go to the next page?

Comment: You could use a flag videoEnded and put it back to false on the else of the condition that would be when you move the video position. Something like this: if (!videoEnded && position == duration) {videoEnded = true; goToNext();} else {videoEnded = false;}

Comment: Sorry, I'm try to fix this bug, the occasional crash emu and 10m start make it really long .It not about that bug i talk early, i have 2 video controller, so everytime app start, it run 2 video at the same time,  buffterfly 7s clip and bee 6s clip soo it change page everytime 6s clip end, that why i thought it accumulate like before, ,i kinda fix it but still a little buggy. after the first run with change page at 6s and the play button still on screen at bee clip then it will run perfectly after,

Comment: Update: I fix it by change chewie controller of clip 2 to autoPlay=false,  autoInitialize: true, it run perfectly if i let i auto play Carousel slide, but if i move slide by my self it will cause bug, gonna find way later., thanks for your help