# Is there any way to add many yt videos on carousel and slide them horizontally (lazy loading) in Flutter?

Tags: flutter, flutter-layout, flutter-android

This is actually a request! I googled that video carousel slider repo or sample for flutter (mobile). But i couldn't find any example.

These are unanswered questions about it:

- [Carousal slider with video player getting memory leak error in flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/63091234/carousal-slider-with-video-player-getting-memory-leak-error-in-flutter)
- [Video Carousel slider for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280668/video-carousel-slider-for-flutter)

I need to show in active index of slider, animated yt video (gif thumbnails) instead a thumbnail image on carousel slider in Flutter mobile app. When i touched on video/gif, it'll replace page and play the video in new page. Unluckily, there's no video carousel slider for Flutter in Google.
Hope someone help me!