# How to show video on carousel using flutter?

Tags: flutter, dart

I am new to flutter. I am trying to show video in a carousel. I am able to show images but when it comes to video I'm stuck. I have searched everywhere but couldn't find any example.

Comment: Can you expand your question to include what you have tried, and why videos don't work where images do?

Answer (score 1):

If you know how to implement a photo carousel, it should be easy to make a video carousel. Just implement a video player using chewie package and just place the video widget instead of the image widget.

> https://pub.dev/packages/chewie

As you have provided no code in your question. So, I do not know why you are stuck in video. Also, you can check the below question/ans:

> [Video Carousel slider for flutter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/58280668/video-carousel-slider-for-flutter)

Answer (score 0):

You can do like this.You have to initialise List of video controllers.You can use https://pub.dev/packages/video_player

```
List<File> videos; 
///initialise multiple controllers
  videos.forEach((element) async {
  VideoPlayerController _controller = VideoPlayerController.file(element);
  _videoController.add(_controller);
});
  _videoController.forEach((element) {
    element.initialize();
  });    
CarouselSlider(
            items: List.generate(videos.length, (index) => AspectRatioVideo(_videoController[index], 1)),
            options: CarouselOptions(
              height: MediaQuery.of(context).size.height/1.5,
              aspectRatio: 16/9,
              viewportFraction: 1,
              initialPage: 0,
              enableInfiniteScroll: false,
              onPageChanged: (index, reason) {
                setState(() {
                  _videoController[index].initialize();
                  _current.value = index;
                });
              },
              reverse: false,
              autoPlay: false,
              autoPlayInterval: Duration(seconds: 3),
              autoPlayAnimationDuration: Duration(milliseconds: 800),
              autoPlayCurve: Curves.fastOutSlowIn,
              enlargeCenterPage: true,
              scrollDirection: Axis.horizontal,
            )
        ),
```